# How to say go-al Yisroel before Shacharis Amida

Tags: tefilla, blessing, chazzan-prayer-leader, shemoneh-esrei, loud-quiet

When the leader gets to just before the *Shacharis Amida*, how should he say the blessing

*go-al Yisroel*:  aloud or saying the word *Yisroel* so the end of it cannot be heard?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21282&st=&pgnum=6 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44187&st=&pgnum=68

Comment: @DoubleAA That's clear enough! Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in [Orach Chaim 111:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=354) states that there should be no Hefsek between Geula and Tefila. Although the Rama says there is no problem answering Amen the accepted custom is that we do not answer Amen after Go'al Yisroel. Both options mentioned are options that are acceptable. Some Shuls the Chazan just says the last word quitely and in some Shuls the Chazan says it out loud and the people say it along with the Chazan. The Chazan should do whatever the Minhag of the Shul he is Davening in does.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=27923&hilite=5abc2ec2-d4fd-4e70-b509-a906fe82ecb5&st=%d7%92%d7%90%d7%9c+%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%9c+&pgnum=25

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29549&hilite=2a65da55-d10a-41e2-a467-af9b28633197&st=%d7%92%d7%90%d7%9c+%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%9c+&pgnum=7

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a source for the acceptability of the "fade-out" method?

Comment: Gershon "The Chazan should do whatever the Minhag of the Shul he is Davening in does." Source? This is a very poor answer. It's just your assertions. "Both options mentioned are options that are acceptable." Source? Rabbis Moshe Shternbuch, Yosef Eliyahu Henkin, Joseph Soloveitchik, Shmuel Wosner, Shlomo Zalman Aurebach, Efraim Greenblatt, Aharon Lichtenstein, Menachem Mendel Schneerson, Shimon Schwab, Seraya Deblitzky, Hershel Schachter and others (not to mention all Sefardim and Temanim) would disagree, I'd imagine. The Mishna Berura didn't even see one of the options as worth discussing.

Answer (score 8):

Chabad custom is to say it at regular volume, see [here](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sefer-haminhagim/11.htm#t80). The halachic sources cited there include Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chayim 66:7, as well as Shulchan Aruch 111 (as [mentioned by Gershon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9670/how-to-say-go-al-yisroel-before-shacharis-amida/9671#9671))

Comment: My impression is that that's the custom among _chasidim_ generally, not just Lubavitch.

Comment: When I've been to Chabad houses, the gabbai announces the page after "go-al Yisroel."

Answer (score 8):

There is a long (20 pages) and detailed discussion of this question in the sefer *Iyunei Halachos* by D. Y Zvi Rabinowitz published in 2003. It includes all the sources that discuss this question and the opinions of the recent *poskim*. While there is no conclusive answer because there are opinions on both sides of the question, it is certainly worthwhile to read to find out what the issues are.

Answer (score 3):

The minhag at my Sephardic community is to say Ga'al Yisra'el out loud, then say "Ad-nai" (as part of "... sefatai tiftah...") in an audible undertone so that the members of the tzibbur would start their amidah right away.