# Should the chazan say "Ga'al Yisra'el" silently?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, hefsek-interruption, amen, loud-quiet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to say go-al Yisroel before Shacharis Amida](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9670/how-to-say-go-al-yisroel-before-shacharis-amida)

According to the Shulchan Aruch ([66:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=197)), one doesn't say "amen" after the chazan says "Ga'al Yisra'el." The Rama says that you do. The Mishnah Brurah (35) says that the proper thing to do is to fulfill all opinions and say the conclusion of the blessing together with the chazan, or to say the words "י"י שפתי תפתח" before the chazan concludes.

I have seen that the practice is for the chazan to say "Ga'al Yisra'el" silently, which seems to be in response to this problem. Is there any source or reason to use this solution other than the two the Mishnah Brurah quotes?

Comment: There are certainly reasons _not_ to use it.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe btw. lemme check.

Comment: Gotcha http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9670/759

Comment: @DoubleAA nu...?

Comment: @DoubleAA I see. (It's interesting that the owner of a post can't close it by his own vote.)

Comment: @IsaacMoses Well, maybe it's different. It's certainly more thorough than the other, but also it asks about a third option and why there would be a preference.

Comment: But compare: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1339/duplicate-answers-on-different-questions

Comment: @DoubleAA The way I understood that in my answer there was when they overlap. In this case they are not only overlapping in one area, but any answer that answers one can answer the other.

Comment: Yud"Yud? Was that necessary?

Comment: @SethJ Are you saying I didn't need the apostrophe, or that I should have used a ה"א? I am not an expert on the laws of writing G-d's name, but I have developed some habits from a long time ago that have stuck (which is, for example, why I write "G-d" instead of "God," though I do use "God" in formal writing).

Comment: The latter. My impression is, though I could be mistaken, that that usage is considered closer to G-d's name than a simple ה׳.