# How does the chazzan say "omein" in the kaddish before the Amida in Mincha and Maariv

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, kaddish, loud-quiet

I asked in [How to say go-al Yisroel before Shacharis Amida](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9670/how-to-say-go-al-yisroel-before-shacharis-amida)

> “When the leader gets to just before the Shacharis Amida, how should
>   he say the blessing go-al Yisroel: aloud or saying the word Yisroel so
>   the end of it cannot be heard?”

Now I would like to know if there are any sources for how to say the word “omein” (aloud or so the end of it cannot be heard) at the end of the half-kaddish before the Amida in

(1) Mincha and

(2) Maariv.

Comment: What about musaf and neilah

Comment: Why would you suspect it should be said quietly?

Comment: @DoubleAA Responses to both comments. I have heard it done with mincha and maariv and not with musaf and neilah. I do not suspect it should be said quietly.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify that in the question. The answer of course to any question like this is the chazan should say everything out loud always. That's what he's there for. I can't think of anything he should say silently which he isn't repeating again out loud for the Tzibur.

Answer (score 2):

I'm "extraplocombing" (extrapolating and combining) the answers from your referenced question regarding Shacharit with [Mishnah Brura 232:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=296). See Sha'arei Tzion #4, who points out that since Ma'ariv is reshut (not obligatory) we are not as concerned about the requirement of *smichat g'ulah litfilah* (loose translation - connecting the concept of redemption as said in the blessing "G'al Yisra'el, to tefillah, meaning Shmoneh Esreh).

Thus, in Shacharit, one should not answer "Amein" to the Bracha "Ga'al Yisra'el" said by the chazzan. Therefore, the custom in many places for the chazzan to say the ending of the bracha silently to prevent people from answering "Amein".

In Ma'ariv, if we are not as strict about the *semicha*, there is more flexibility for the chazzan to say the "Amen of Kaddish aloud, and people can answer "Amein" as well. The mechaber mentions that one can even include "Barchu" (I haven't seen this done, anywhere) prior to the start of Shmoneh Esreh in Ma'ariv.

Re - Mincha - there is no "Ge'ulah" in Mincha, so the concerns of *semicha* don't apply, and the Chazan should say "Amein" aloud and everyone can answer with no problems.